# -bash: ../binutils-2.38/configure: Permission denied

Tags: compile, gcc

I follow Bare Bones Tutorial on OSDev wiki then I type this:

```
../binutils-2.38/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
```

Then I get this error:

```
-bash: ../binutils-2.38/configure: Permission denied
```

I use ubuntu wsl, I download binutils-2.38 and gcc-11.4.0